How to allow TikTok embed player to open application store?
I'm trying to embed TikTok player using https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/embed-player?enter_method=left_navigation.
When interacting with comments button on mobile devices without having TikTok app installed - default behaviour is to redirect App store.
But, it doesn't work, and instead throws an error:
Not allowed to launch '<URL>' because a user gesture is required.
Breaking the whole player.
How do I allow iframe to perform this redirect?
